# IIS Express: treat files from subfolder as if they're in root

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I have an MVC project where I have a large number of static html pages that I want to serve from the root of the site. However I don't want them cluttering up the root folder of my project so I put them in a subfolder `StaticHtml`. I have a publish action which copies the contents of this folder to the root of the output directory.

This works great when publishing, but when I try to debug in VS I cannot find any way to get IIS Express to serve that folder as if it was from root. I tried mapping the `/` virtual directory to both the root and `StaticHtml` folders, but it just errored out.

In other words I want requests to be served like this:

```
GET /                           -> HomeController Default Action
GET /Home                       -> HomeController Default Action
GET /Other/Thing                -> OtherController.Thing Action
GET /Home.jpg                   -> /Home.jpg
GET /Home.html                  -> /StaticHtml/Home.html
GET /NotAController/Thing.html  -> /StaticHtml/NotAController/Thing.html
GET /NotAController/Image.jpg   -> /NotAController/Image.jpg
GET /StaticHtml/Home.html       -> [Don't care, this should never be requested]
```

*Note for clarity: `NotAController` does not match any defined controller names; there will never be a conflict there.*

In essence I am trying to replicate the behavior of my publish action (copying `StaticHtml` to `/`) while using IIS Express to debug. Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? as I'm in the same boat

Comment: Nope, no luck. I've been living without that convenience =\. If you upvote, someone might be more likely to see and answer it.

Comment: Finally found a solution that worked for me...it's to do with URL rewrite and I'm sure it'll work for you...check it out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780087/how-do-i-change-the-root-path-of-a-asp-net-webapi-application

Comment: Whoa, somehow I searched for over an hour on here and never found that one! I'll try it out on Monday and if it works I'll flag this question as a dupe.