# Owin PhysicalFileServer not behaving as expected

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin, static-files

I have read numerous links on SO and I appear to be doing toe right thing but it won't serve files.

My simplified directory structure is below:

```
     root
       wwwroot
         css
           si.css <--- this is an actual file.
       index.html
```

My code follows.

```
        PhysicalFileSystem physicalFileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@"./wwwroot");
        FileServerOptions options = new FileServerOptions
        {
            EnableDefaultFiles = false,
            EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true,
            FileSystem = physicalFileSystem
        };

        options.StaticFileOptions.FileSystem = physicalFileSystem;
        options.StaticFileOptions.ServeUnknownFileTypes = true;
        options.DefaultFilesOptions.DefaultFileNames = new[]
        {
            "index.html"
        };

        app.UseFileServer(options);
```

I originally had EnableDefaultFiles = true and EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false, but I reversed them to diagnose.

With it in the proper position http://localhost:port found index.html but then gave a 404 on:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/si.css">
```

So I changed them for diagnostics.

Now http://localhos:port yields a listing of the wwwroot directory.

If I click on the folder css it shows me a listing of the wwwroot/css directory but if I then click on the file si.css I get a 404 and the response from IIS is that the path root\css\si.css was used.

If I change the url to http://localhost:port/wwwroot/css/si.css the file is returned. In other words, when looking for directories, the wwwroot is used but when looking for files, it isn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Static%20Files%20on%20IIS

Comment: After much more surfing and asking the question a lot of different ways, I eventually found the solution right here on SO. [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780087/how-do-i-change-the-root-path-of-a-asp-net-webapi-application) provided the answer. It turns out neither UseFileServer nor UseStaticFiles was needed.