# IISExpress and Web Api virtual path issue

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I would like to set my web site's root path to fall in my physical path of C:\\dist. But when I change the iisexpress virtual path / to point to this physical path, my web api calls start to fail as they go off of the physical root of my project. How can I have both pathing coexist?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735713/creating-virtual-directories-in-iis-express would be my suggestion.

Comment: I found the answer in another stack posting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780087/how-do-i-change-the-root-path-of-a-asp-net-webapi-application